# In python, how do you know the node structure and attribute of an XML?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, xml.etree

In Python 3 I have an XML file and I want to turn it into pandas dataframe

For this I thought of using the xml.etree.ElementTree Python module. Here an example [tutorial](https://medium.com/@robertopreste/from-xml-to-pandas-dataframes-9292980b1c1c)

However, I don't know what the XML node and attribute structure is.

It is an XML about TV and radio channels, with names and location of each broadcaster. But I don't know how to check the XML node and attribute structure. I need to know this to populate the dataframe columns that I will create

This XML is on a public [site](http://sistemas.anatel.gov.br/se/public/view/b/srd.php), but has no data dictionary. The XML file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RlJ3TXxTyWSP_N-YYiJkFVi1-g8HC-N2/view?usp=sharing).

Please, does anyone know how i can see this?

Comment: open xml in any text editor to see structure. Use `find()` to find needed element and don't care of structure - you don't have to use full path to node.

Comment: Thanks @furas I'll try. The problem is that a file a bit big to open in text editor

Comment: Any modern text editor should be able to open it fine (notepad++/vs code/sublime text)

Comment: in Linux in console you could use command `more filename` or `less filename` to display it partially (and press space to display next page). In Windows should be also command `more`. But you can use Python `open()` and `read(some_value)` in loop to read and  display it partially.